# Cloud Hosting platform selection

Tags: cloud

We have a requirement for a cloud hosting platform that is cheap, does not need too much processing power or storage.

1. AWS EC2 onDemand instances are priced per hour.  Is it correct to assume that yearly cost would be directly cph*24*365? Or is it load based? How do I give the client an estimate if load based?
2. Is there any opinion on Digital Ocean versus AWS versus Google Cloud versus Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. AWS has so-called reserved instances that you can purchase for 1 year and pay up to 40% less than the on-demand price. Other providers also have similar kind of discounts. As of my knowledge, no cloud provider prices for instances are based on load.
2. I prefer Google cloud because of its price/performance ratio and consistent and clear API. But this is just my personal opinion.